# Document editor in angular2?

Tags: angular, editor, angular2-components, webodf

Is there any document editor component in angular2 .I find webodf document editor in angular. but I have not seen any  document editor in angular2 kindly suggest me some document editor component available in angular2 or any other way to do this.

Comment: why not to use webodf

Comment: Hi, did you find solution ?